# Magento2.3: Refer a friend feature

Tags: magento2.3, customer, account-dashboard

I'm using Magento 2.3 EE. In Account dashboard, I can see the account navigation links. I want to add a feature called "Refer a Friend". Is this something default in Magento 2.

Could anyone please guide me?

Comment: In default Magento 2 there is no such feature available. You can check these extensions. [link](https://www.google.com/search?q=refer+a+friend+magento+2)

Comment: Thanks for the information. Let me check them.